# xcode enable push notifications

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

Im trying for a whole day now to get firebase push notifications working.
In almost every tutorial there is a toggle button for push notifications in xcode, in my setup i can not find the toggle button. I can add push notification in the Singing & Capabilities view. And I can see the pus notifications heading, however there is no toggle button.
Im a member of a apple developer team account do I need to get special permissions?

[image]

When I view the app config (i can not edit the config) at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list I see the push notifications is checked.

[image]

Im running xcode 11.2.1 on osx 10.15.1

Any pointers are appreciated.

When looking at the capabilities 6 it states: push notifications.

[image]

Comment: Have you purchased the apple developer account? Because some of the features would only be visible to you if you have purchased the apple developer account by paying them $100?

Comment: @MandeepSingh we have a license for our business but im a developer not admin.